# How to constantly update y axis using a C# function to update a Live (Streaming) Chart.js Chart in ASP.NET core Web Application Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, chart.js

I'm having a problem with my Chart.js live chart where the Y-axis will not update. I'm using RazorPages to call a C# function that generates a random number located in cshtml.cs side of the RazorPage. When I call this function in my cshtml portion of the Razorpage, it will take the first value generated from the function and constantly stream that one value.

Here is some code for reference.

C# code in cshtml.cs

```
 public class IndexModel:PageModel
 {
      public int RNG(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(1, 10);
       return num;
     }
 }
```

Relevant Javascript code in cshtml.cs

```
function onRefresh(chart) {
 chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
 dataset.data.push({
    x: Date.now(),
    y: @Model.RNG() //Where I call my c# function
  });
 });
}
var config_Chart = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Chart Data',
                backgroundColor: 
                color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: chartColors.red,
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
                borderDash: [8, 4],
                data: []
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart (Real Time)'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'realtime'
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'value'
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false
            },
            plugins: {
                streaming: {
                    duration: 20000,
                    refresh: 1000,
                    delay: 2000,
                    onRefresh: onRefresh
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

How do I get the chart to constantly update the Y axis with the different numbers generated from my c# function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly. The code is executed only once when the request is sent to server.

In order to achieve your goals, you need create a server side code snippet to generate data. For example, if you prefer `Razor Page`, create a `OnGetRefresh()` handler as below:

```
public IActionResult OnGetRefresh()
{
    return new JsonResult(this.RNG());
}

private int RNG(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    return num;
}
```

And then pull data when `onRefresh` using Ajax or `websocket`. Here's a demo that uses Ajax to get the data from server:

```
function onRefresh(chart) {
    function pushData(yData){
        chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.data.push({ x: Date.now(), y:yData });
        });
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // you might want to custom the url
    var handlerUrl = '/Index?handler=Refresh';
    xhr.open('GET', handlerUrl , true);  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                pushData(xhr.responseText);
                return;
            } 
            console.log("error happens: receives a status code ",xhr.status)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

A Working Demo Using your config:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I needed to understand.