# Constant updating of x- and y-axis using a C# function to update a Chart.js chart in ASP.NET core Web Application Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, web-applications, chart.js

I am trying to iterate over 2 lists that constantly update my Chart.js chart. Since there are several thousand data points I can't use a static graph. After trying a buffer queue using SignalR and being semi successful I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793250/how-to-constantly-update-y-axis-using-a-c-sharp-function-to-update-a-live-strea/56800581#56800581) which is basically what I am trying to accomplish but only for the y axis.
However I am not getting this to work since I am quite new to Ajax handlers and the update plugin for Chart.Js is also something i am not used to yet.

Here is my current .cshtml:

```
@page
@model Proj.Pages.Visualization.VisualizationMainModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CSV Data Visualization";
}

<html>

 <div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.27.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@1.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@2.0.0"></script>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new myChart (ctx {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Chart Data',
                borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                fill: false,
                tension: 0,
                data: []
            }]
        },
        options={
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'realtime'
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Value'
                    }
                }]
            },
            plugins: {
                streaming: {
                    duration: 20000,
                    refresh: 1000,
                    delay: 2000,
                    onRefresh: onRefresh
                }
            }
        }
    });

    function onRefresh(chart) {
        function pushData(xData, yData) {
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.data.push({ x: xData, y: yData });
            });
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // you might want to custom the url
        var handlerUrl = '/Index?handler=Refresh';
        xhr.open('GET', handlerUrl, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    pushData(xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("error happens: receives a status code ", xhr.status)
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>

</html>
```

And .cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Proj.Pages.Visualization
{
    public class VisualizationMainModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<string> Time = new();

        public List<string> Value = new();

        public int i = 0;

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Content\rawData.csv");

            using (StreamReader sr = new(filepath))
            {
                sr.ReadLine();

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                    // Set up line splitting
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(";");

                    Time.Add(values[0]);
                    Value.Add(values[1]);
                    }
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetRefresh()
        {
            return new JsonResult(this.XValue(), this.YValue());
        }

        private string XValue()
        {
            string X = Time[i];
            return X;
        }

        private string YValue()
        {
            string Y = Value[i];
            i += 1;
            return Y;
        }
    }
}
```

There is probably a more direct way to get the .csv entries as direct data points but for now just getting this to show up and update every few ms would be my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think, after a quick glance, and if the C# code is correct, you just would have to add a call to the chart `update` function, in the `pushData` function *([link to the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html))*.

**Update:** **AND** fix atleast all bugs listed below *(I **didn't** check the C# code, there might be some there also)*.

```
    function pushData(xData, yData) {
        chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.data.push({ x: xData, y: yData });
        });
        chart.update();
    }
```

> But I **strongly** recommend checking the browser console, since your javascript code seems to have some/alot of errors, *like for example:*
>
> - `chart = new myChart (...)` should be `chart = new Chart (...)`
> - `new Chart (ctx {...})` a comma is missing between `ctx` and the config object, so  `new Chart (ctx, {...})`.
> - in the config object `options={` the equal sign should be a colon `options:{`
> - `pushData(xhr.responseText);` is passing a string to the `pushData` function, but in the function your are accessing two parameters `function pushData(xData, yData) { ... }`. `xData` and
>   `yData` this will not work. `xData` will always be the returned data and `yData` will be always `undefined`.
>
> those are the ones I caught just browsing your code.

***btw.:*** you can check what the Ajax call returns, if you output the result to the console. *AND* `xhr.responseText` is a string, not a json object (use `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` to convert this, for example).

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var handlerUrl = '/Index?handler=Refresh';
    xhr.open('GET', handlerUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                console.info(xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }
            console.log("error happens: receives a status code ", xhr.status)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
```

**Bonus Info:**
If you don't need to support older browsers, instead of the `XMLHttpRequest` I would recommend `fetch` ([link to mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)), this is the *"modern way"* and easier to use.

The following code is comparable to your `XMLHttpRequest` code piece, is much shorter and easier to read.

```
fetch('/Index?handler=Refresh')
    .then((response) => response.json())  
    // And data will be a json object and no convertion needed
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```